# CSS adding opaque color overlay to circle image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to crop an image into a circle and apply a gray filter with text on top. The problem I'm running into is twofold. One, since my system allows users to upload images as a profile picture, the size of the circle clip-path changes depending on the size of the original image, which then in turn does not allow me to place a proper gray filter on the image. Any advice on how to fix this? The end result should be the image on the right being a circle with a gray filter.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/dansbyt/pen/wvzyJzj

HTML:

```
<div class="center">
  <img class='pic large primary' src='../resources/pics/23.png'>
  <div class='picgroup large'>
    <div class='count'>+14</div>
    <img class='pic large secondary' src='../resources/pics/81.png'>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pic {clip-path: circle();}
.primary {z-index: 3}
.secondary {z-index: 0; margin-left: -50px; margin-bottom: -30px}
.large.primary {width: 220px}
.large.secondary {width: 170px}
.small.primary {width: 150px}
.small.secondary {width: 116px}
.pic img{float:right; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; display: block;}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;}

.secondary img{object-fit: cover}

.picgroup {position: relative}
.small.picgroup:before {
  width:116px; height: 116px;
  margin-top: 20px;}
.large.picgroup:before {
  width:150%; height: 150%;
  margin-top: -30px;}
.picgroup:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  margin-left: -50px; 
  clip-path: circle();
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 2;
}

.picgroup .count {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #E5E5E5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-65%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to apply `filter: brightness()` ?

Comment: Sweet, that works! Thank you. For learning sake, how would I do this if I wanted the end result to be a green or maybe pink overlay?

Comment: you can place an element on top of the image using position absolute and give background color and play with opacity to make it as u want. the absolute element should be the same height and width though

Comment: @ZiaAhmad Right, I tried doing that, but like I said in the original post, users are able to upload their own picture so I cannot predict the height and width.

Comment: actually you can limit height and width of the parent div (the image is in) and set image to 100% width

Answer (score 0):

For color overlay, you can use the `brightness()` and `hue-rotate()` rules together for `.secondary`. Like this:

```
.secondary {
   ...
   filter: brightness(0.5) hue-rotate(90deg);
}
```

```css
.pic {clip-path: circle();}
.primary {z-index: 3}

.secondary {z-index: 0; margin-left: -50px; margin-bottom: -30px;
filter: brightness(0.5) hue-rotate(90deg);
}

.large.primary {width: 220px}
.large.secondary {width: 170px}
.small.primary {width: 150px}
.small.secondary {width: 116px}
.pic img{float:right; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; display: block;}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;}

.secondary img{object-fit: cover}

.picgroup {position: relative}
.small.picgroup:before {
  width:116px; height: 116px;
  margin-top: 20px;}
  
/*.large.picgroup:before {
  width:150%; height: 150%;
  margin-top: -30px;}*/
  
.picgroup:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  margin-left: -50px; 
  clip-path: circle();
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 2;
}

.picgroup .count {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #E5E5E5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-65%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <img class='pic large primary' src='https://mrdansby.com/resources/pics/23.png'>
  <div class='picgroup large'>
    <div class='count'>+14</div>
    <img class='pic large secondary' src='https://mrdansby.com/resources/pics/81.png'>
  </div>
</div>
```